# How can I retrieve values from the database from a specific users?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I want to be able to retrieve values from the database  from a
specific user, which in this case `@Model.user.Xp`, it does not work, I
just get 0.

```
@model TheQuizR.Models.IndexViewModel

@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <div class="blue">
                @User.Identity.GetUserName()<br />
        </div>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            Title
            <span class="badge">@Model.user.Xp</span>                                   
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
```

In the `IndexViewModel` I have this:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{

    public ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();

    public bool HasPassword { get; set; }
    public IList<UserLoginInfo> Logins { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactor { get; set; }
    public bool BrowserRemembered { get; set; }

}
```

In the `ApplicationUser` class I have all the properties:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 5000000)]
    public int Xp { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 100000)]
}
```

I cant get the id and the username thru Microsoft.AspNet.Identity (the one mark in yellow). I can't get all the other properties.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to find the user in controller. Then you can create another model or use Viewbag.

```
string username = User.Identity.GetUserName();
var user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserAD == username);
ViewBag.userIDconnected = user.ID;
```

View -

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <div class="blue">
    </div>

    <li class="list-group-item">
        Title
        <span class="badge">@ViewBag.userIDconnected</span>                                   
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
```

Comment: I was probably a bit unclear in my question, User.Identity.GetUserName () is no problem to show, it's all the other properties that I can not see.

Comment: Do you fill the model with proper data in controller ? You can not fill model in view.

Comment: I think I solved it thanks to your answer above =) Nice

Comment: No problem, you can mark it as solving answer or how its called :)